re-index JSON keys based on iteration values
I got this sample JSON data
var default_data = 
[ 
  {
    pack0: 'TEXT',
    pack1: 'DETAILS',
    pack2: 'ITEM1',
    pack3: 'ITEM2',
    pack4: 'PERFECT'
  },
  {
    pack0: 'TEXT',
    pack1: 'DETAILS2',
    pack2: 'ABC123',
    pack3: 'TEST2',
    pack4: 'ITEM2'
  }
];

After deleting all the pack1 elements like,
default_data.forEach(item => { delete item.pack1; });
JSON data turned to this
[ 
  {
    pack0: 'TEXT',
    pack2: 'ITEM1',
    pack3: 'ITEM2',
    pack4: 'PERFECT'
  },
  {
    pack0: 'TEXT',
    pack2: 'ABC123',
    pack3: 'TEST2',
    pack4: 'ITEM2'
  }
]

Any efficient way to re-index the keys (0,2,3,4) into (0,1,2,3) to make the it like
[ 
  {
    pack0: 'TEXT',
    pack1: 'ITEM1',
    pack2: 'ITEM2',
    pack3: 'PERFECT'
  },
  {
    pack0: 'TEXT',
    pack1: 'ABC123',
    pack2: 'TEST2',
    pack3: 'ITEM2'
  }
]

I've Not tried anything yet

most efficient might be not to have to reindex at all? if you care about element order, why not use an array instead of an object? a = [ {pack:['TEXT','DETAILS','ITEM1','ITEM2','PERFECT']}, {pack:['TEXT','DETAILS2','ABC123','TEST2','ITEM2'] } ]; a.forEach(e => {e.pack.splice(1,1)});

appreciate the reply and your idea. I was able to solved it eventually. But still looking for a better approach.

https://jsfiddle.net/caloyregs/k173t5a6/5/
